# Issue with If Statement in VB

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I'm new to VB so I apologize if the answer is obvious but I am attempting to execute an `if else` statement.

My logic behind it is that

> If `myId` = 10, 11 or 12, execute `a`, if not, execute `b`

I am not getting the expected result which makes me believe my syntax in the `if else` statement is not correct.

Here is the code:

```vb
If ProfileLists.myId = 10 Or ProfileLists.myId = 11 Or ProfileLists.myId = 12 Then
    For Each item As Dictionary(Of String, Object) In data("Column1")
        If (Not CheckReturnedListForSectors(item.ElementAt(2).Value, item.ElementAt(0).Value)) Then
            reports.Rows.Add(item.ElementAt(4).Value, RoundGrowthValue(item.ElementAt(5).Value), TrimExecSummary(item.ElementAt(6).Value), ConvertReportUrl(item.ElementAt(9).Value))
        End If
    Next
    For Each item As Dictionary(Of String, Object) In data("Column1")
        If (Not CheckReturnedListForSectors(item.ElementAt(2).Value, item.ElementAt(0).Value)) Then
            reports.Rows.Add(item.ElementAt(4).Value, RoundGrowthValue(item.ElementAt(7).Value), TrimExecSummary(item.ElementAt(5).Value), ConvertReportUrl(item.ElementAt(7).Value))
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Comment: What is "b" in the code you posted? I only see "a".

Comment: Notice how your `If` lacks an `Else`? This code will only do `a` unless you put in an else. By the looks of it, your second `for each` is the `b`, so make sure to put an else before that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code does not contain a B code. A valid VB If looks like this:

```
If something Then
     a()
Else
     b()
End If
```